# Launching a ListActivity from another Activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-intent

I am creating an application that saves GPS coordinates; I have created a button which launches a new Activity to display, as a list all the save coordinates. The program crashes a soon as I hit the button, here is what I am doing.

class 1:

```
        public void openLatLonData(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GpsDataList.class);
        ArrayList<String> allLocalStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i =0; i< AllLocals.size();i++)
        {
            allLocalStrings.add(AllLocals.get(i).getLat());
            allLocalStrings.add(AllLocals.get(i).getLon());
        }
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", allLocalStrings);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This method calls the new activity:

```
public class GpsDataList extends ListActivity
```

{

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundleIn) 
{
    super.onCreate(bundleIn);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<String>();

    listData = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("data");

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData));
  getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  //finish();

}
```

}

the button contains the following XML:

```
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Show Collected Data" 
android:id="@+id/view_lat_lon_data" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:onClick="openLatLonData">
</Button>
```

And I have added a new .xml file named gpsdatalist.xml under the res/layout folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Lastly the manifest contains this: .

I believe I have all the pieces in play- Hopefully someones see the mistake
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: you need a list tag in the xml and also make sure u have registered the activity in the manifest file

Comment: Any updates on this? I have also posted an almost similiar  here.: 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964888/fetching-data-from-intent-causes-app-to-crash  Are you getting the same error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file?
Anyway, your best clue resides in the logcat of your exception. You will solve it in 2 seconds after cheking the logcat.